# React passing state to children with Navbar

Tags: reactjs, state, navbar, children

I have a simple react Navbar from bootstrap and I want to pass a userid from the navbar to a child.

I can do that working but when so, the child component is shown twice, once above the navbar and the second time below.

This happens only when I insert this command:

```js
<UserConfig userid={this.state.user.userid} />
```

Here is a part of my App.js with the navigation
I tried many places to paste it in, but nothing worked

```js
  render() {
    
    console.log(this.state.user.userid);
      return (  
      
      <div className="App container" >
        <UserConfig userid={this.state.user.userid} />
        <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <Link to="/">Hallo {jwt_decode(authentication.getAccessToken()).given_name}!</Link>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
         </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav pullRight>
              <LinkContainer to="/config">
                <NavItem >Konfiguration</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/logout">
                <NavItem>Logout</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/callback">
                <NavItem>Callback</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In my UserConfig.js I just use this.props.userid which shows the value only when the navbar is crashed.....

Could you please help me to get that working?
Actually I just want to pass down the userid from App.js to UserConfig.js WITHOUT destroying my navigation.

UserConfig

```js
  render() {   
    console.log(this.props.userid); 
    return (

      <div className="Login">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup controlId="hersteller" >
            <ControlLabel >Hersteller</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              autoFocus
              type="text"
              value={this.state.hersteller}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
  
        ......
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you put the UserConfig component in?

Comment: No, everything fine and the value is shown in the component, but as mentioned, the component (that contains a form) is shown twice

Comment: What does your UserConfig component look like?

Comment: just addad a small snippet of UserConfig, If you need more please give me the details.

Answer (score 0):

[What is the correct way to pass props to NavItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941569/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pass-props-to-navitem)

From this question... try this:

```
<LinkContainer to="/config">
    <NavItem data-userid={this.state.userid} >Konfiguration</NavItem>
</LinkContainer>
```

I am assuming that is config page you are trying to get the value too? You can then remove the UserConfig component above the navigation (which should remove the double render).

Comment: thank you, I tried that, but then i get undefined for the value for userid (changed to this.state.user.userid)